# Error in gfortran make function: invalid option -- I

Tags: gcc, gfortran, openmpi

I have the following simple code running with brew linked to gcc and openmpi:

```
 mpif90 test.f90 ./test
```

The following error is returned:

```
 /opt/local/bin/gfortran: invalid option -- I
 Usage: gcov [OPTION]... SOURCE|OBJ...

 Print code coverage information.

   -h, --help                      Print this help, then exit
   -a, --all-blocks                Show information for every basic block
   -b, --branch-probabilities      Include branch probabilities in output
   -c, --branch-counts             Output counts of branches taken
                                rather than percentages
   -d, --display-progress          Display progress information
   -f, --function-summaries        Output summaries for each function
    -i, --intermediate-format       Output .gcov file in intermediate text format
     -l, --long-file-names           Use long output file names for included
                                source files
     -m, --demangled-names           Output demangled function names
     -n, --no-output                 Do not create an output file
     -o, --object-directory DIR|FILE Search for object files in DIR or called FILE
     -p, --preserve-paths            Preserve all pathname components
     -r, --relative-only             Only show data for relative sources
     -s, --source-prefix DIR         Source prefix to elide
     -u, --unconditional-branches    Show unconditional branch counts too
     -v, --version                   Print version number, then exit

   For bug reporting instructions, please see:
   <https://trac.macports.org/newticket>.
```

I am not sure what the problem is. Any thoughts? Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `mpif90 test.f90 ./test`? Are you missing an `-o` there, or is `./test` source/link object?

Comment: @facescalus With the `-o` in there the error still appears. `./test` is the executable file.

Comment: As in `mpif90 test.f90 -o ./test`? If that's giving the output you give above then it may be good to try reinstalling things. How did you install and configure the environment for Open MPI?

Comment: @fancescalus I reinstalled openmpi with `brew install open-mpi` and this is all I have done to configure it.

Comment: @facescalus I have installed and updated the environment as `brew install gcc` and `brew install open-mpi`. Both are linked to brew as `brew link gcc` and `brew link open-mpi` with the correct symlink file paths. Then I run `brew cleanup`. Finally, `mpif90 test.f90 -o ./test` returns the error `/opt/local/bin/gfortran: invalid option -- I
Usage: gcov [OPTION]... SOURCE|OBJ...` (as shown above).

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you further, but please [edit] those details in to the question. Adding the [tag:macos] tag may also help having the question seen by someone more familiar with your environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was there were other `/bin/` directories that had older versions of gcc and  openmpi. When updating, the new files from `/lib/` directories needed to be trasnfered to the `/Cellar/` directories. The problem is fixed when first uninstalling all old macports and compilers with incorrect files and/or paths as `sudo port -fp uninstall installed`, and `brew uninstall openmpi`, and `brew uninstall gcc`. Then reinstall new homebrew compilers `brew install gcc`, `brew install openmpi`. This gives the correct paths with configured files when submitting a make file.